# Access PDF file stored in bundle for Printing as NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to print pdf which is stored in my bundle, below is the code but for some reason it prints out images perfectly fine but when i give the pdf path to printingItem it does not respond and keeps loading...., Please suggest.

```
NSString *pdfPath = @"Settings.bundle/test.pdf";
NSData *dataPDF = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];

UIPrintInteractionController *pc = [UIPrintInteractionController
                                    sharedPrintController];
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
printInfo.jobName =@"Report";

pc.printInfo = printInfo;
pc.showsPageRange = YES;
pc.printingItem = dataPDF;
//pc.printingItem

UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed,
  NSError *error) {
    if(!completed && error){
        NSLog(@"Print failed - domain: %@ error code %ld", error.domain,
              (long)error.code);
    }
};

[pc presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is good enough and I tried this in my Xcode and worked perfect. 
The only one line different from your code was:

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@".pdf"];
```

OR your pdf are just corrupted data. You should check it also.